# Blocking Powershell with GPO

Tags: powershell, group-policy, windows-server-2012, windows-server, windows-server-2016

My manager has told me that they want Powershell to be executed only in servers with the admin account, so I created a GPO that blocks Powershell.exe and Powershell_ise.exe with "Don't run specified Windows applications".

A few days ago I discovered that I can still run powershell via cmd just executing powershell -c or simply powershell, and I'm not blocking cmd because I need it for support and administrative tasks in workstations.

After researching a bit I tried to set a hash SRP blocking powershell and ise. The thing is that it doesn't apply even that the delegation is fine, the OU is fine, the permissions of the groups are fine. I mean, I can see that a user is getting the GPO and it's in one of the groups that are reading the GPO and applying it.

I have been trying differents OUs, groups, accounts, types of SRP, but nothing works for me.

Do you have some advice for this situation? Thanks in advance

Edit: I wont want to block powershell's core because some processes or tasks wont be able to run. So the idea is to block the access to powershell for certain users (or computers)

Comment: You can separate workstations by OUs

Comment: @Alex You are applying "Don't run specified Windows applications" for Powershell.exe and powershell_ise.exe but not cmd.exe. Sounds like if you also disallow those same group of users from running cmd.exe, that may be a simple solution to that.

Comment: FYI, Powershell.exe and Powershell_ise.ex, pwsh.exe is not PowerShell. They are simply shells to run PS code. One can run PS code without using them. There are several articles on the web covering that topic, or one can just use WMIC.exe to do what PS can.  [Have you looked the other constraints that PS allows for](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+constrained%27&t=h_&ia=web)?

Comment: There is even Excel and Word methods to execute powershell. You really need some sort of endpoint protection on the workstations to prevent all types of methods of executing powershell. If you set some software restriction policies with applocker settings you can workaround better securing. I don't see the security concern with powershell.exe and powershell_ise.exe if you allow executing non binary code via other methods such as wmic, wscript, cscript, vbs, etc. Lockdown vs productivity in your case. I lock down some public computers super tight so depends on your needs and environment too.

Comment: Audit [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging_windows?view=powershell-7.2), [2](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/greater-visibilityt), [log](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-logging-2/), and react to it all, in real-time. Have automated processes to trap for it and take whatever action on that, including HR actions as needed. [Again, one does not need 'p*.exe' to run PS code. There are many articles on that topic](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27run+powershell+scripts+without+powershell%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: With tight permissions and an execution policy via GPO I think I could reach this protection, better than blocking Powershell with applocker.

Answer (score 0):

### The Short Answer

The short answer to your question is not to try to prevent users from opening PowerShell. Why? PowerShell is a program, not a security boundary. For details, read on.

### Preventing PowerShell from Running Does Not Increase Security

Blocking PowerShell, or preventing PowerShell scripts from running, does not increase security. In Windows, the user's *account* is the security boundary, *not programs a user runs*. The fact that a user can open PowerShell or run PowerShell scripts does not allow the user to bypass whatever security controls are present for their account.

### PowerShell Execution Policy Is A Safety Feature, Not A Security Boundary

PowerShell's execution policy is a widely misunderstood feature that tends to be (ab)used to try to stop users from running PowerShell scripts under the mistaken notion that this somehow increases security.

PowerShell's execution policy is a safety feature that was designed to prevent accidental execution of unsigned scripts. Bruce Payette, one of the principal PowerShell designers, says exactly this in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772982/) on StackOverflow.

> `ExecutionPolicy` is not a security boundary. As someone opined elsewhere in a comment<sup>1</sup>, it is a safety feature. Think seat belt not door lock. But seat belts mitigate risk so it's better to use them than not. `ExecutionPolicy` mitigates the risk of unintentionally running malicious code. The generally recommended minimum policy is `RemoteSigned`.

<sup>1</sup>The "someone" he was referring to is yours truly.